# C: strtok value gives back null

Tags: c++, c, cstring, strtok

I am trying to parse a HTTP request header. I need to pickup the first line:

**GET / HTTP/1.1**

However, the output for the code below is:

```
Method: (null)
Filename: (null)
Version: (null)
Client hostname: (null)
```

**Why?**

Code:

```
    char *token;
    const char delimiter[2] = " ";
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
```

Comment: You are passing `NULL` in the first call to `strtok()`. Where's your buffer with the request? You should be passing it to `strtok()` in the first call.

Comment: You must first call `strtok()` with a non-NULL argument, but you should be passing the line (buffer) that you're parsing to it. After the first call, you need to call it with the NULL argument so it continues where it left off.

Comment: Great minds think alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delimiter has to be " \r\n", otherwise some parts will be concatenated

```
    // Parse the request                                                                                  
    char *token;
    const char delimiter[6] = " \r\n";

    token = strtok(buffer, delimiter);
    method = token;
    printf("Method: %s\n", method);

    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    filename = token;
    printf("Filename: %s\n", filename);

    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    version = token;
    printf("Version: %s\n", version);

    while (token != NULL) {
      if (strstr(token, "Host:") != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        client_hostname = token;
        break;
      }
      token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }

    printf("Client hostname: %s\n", client_hostname);
```

Answer (score 4):

The first time you call strtok you need to provide the string you want to split as the first argument.  Subsequent calls to strtok need to use NULL as the first argument to get subsequent delimited strings.

Good luck.

Comment: Oh, thanks - my mistake. OK, now only the hostname is null - why?

Comment: OK, i split the request by " " delimiter. However, first and second lines are separated with \r\n - and they don't get split. Can i specify multiple split options?

Comment: @chuckfinley Yep, and that's what you need to do. Give it `" \n"`. And note that when you enter `if (strcmp(token, "Host:") == 0)`, you need to perform another `strtok()` to get the actual hostname.

Comment: @Filipe - yes, i've done the second part already. I'll try multiple split options and let you know how i get on